# Router lights are green, still unable to access internet

Tags: router, internet, adsl, adsl-router

I have a TP Link modem router (TD-W8901N 150 Mbps wireless-n ADSL2+ modem router). My ISP had given me a phone along with the connection. But since I didn't need it, I removed the splitters and connected the phone line directly to the router. The router is just a month old.

Since the last few days, I am unable to access internet. **All the lights on the device are green**.

I have tried **resetting the router and even powercycling**. Nothing helped...

Here's the `ipconfig /all` info:

```
Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Niki-PC  
Primary Dns Suffix . . . . . . . :  
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed  
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:  

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :  
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter  
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 12-B7-C3-F9-DB-03  
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:  

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :  
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter  
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 52-B7-C3-F9-DB-03  
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:  

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :  
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Net
work Adapter  
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 50-B7-C3-F9-DB-03  
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1403:68ce:fe4a:ef62%4(Preferred)  
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.101(Preferred)  
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, August 10, 2015 5:20:17 PM  
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, August 13, 2015 5:20:17 PM  
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1  
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1  
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 407943107  
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-E4-43-29-18-67-B0-20-5E-EE  

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1  
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled  

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:  

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :  
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller  
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 18-67-B0-20-5E-EE  
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 19:  

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :  
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface  
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:18b2:b8a5:8a3b:a9f6(Pref
erred)  
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::18b2:b8a5:8a3b:a9f6%6(Preferred)  
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::  
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 201326592  
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-E4-43-29-18-67-B0-20-5E-EE  

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled  

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C6A69B79-043D-4D8D-ABB5-C66BB98F9437}:  

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :  
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2  
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Did you try pinging?

Comment: can you ping google.com ? Also trying changing your DNS to 8.8.8.8

Comment: ping 8.8.8.8 instead of pinging google.com. if ping 8.8.8.8 works - and ping google.com does not work, the failure is on DNS side. if  ping 8.8.8.8 fails, its layer 1 or layer 2 failure.

Comment: By "splitter" do you mean "splitter" (http://www.pcez.co.uk/admin/images/products/1374509579.jpg) or "filter" (http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61cn4bK-ZmL._SL1500_.jpg)? The filter is crucial for (A)DSL connections...

Comment: 1. ping default gateway: ping 192.168.1.1 ( even it seems u already got IP from DHCP) 2. ping internet: ping 8.8.8.8 (google dns) 3. ping a FQDN: ping www.google.com 4.  whats the output? and let us know what you did in past few days on your system, anything might be related to the issue

Comment: @BigChris, I'm not using a filter either, as my copper wires (VDSL to be precise) are *only* used for internet (including VoIP), not for POTS voice, and my ISP (XS4ALL, the Netherlands) recommends not using the filter then.

Comment: @BigChris- its adsl splitter, I confirmed.

Comment: @Botmaster- 1)ping is a  success, 2) request timed out, 3) request timed out. I havent installed any new software not did I make any changes.

Comment: My concern is that because your modem is an ADSL2+ and you're connecting the modem as if it were a VDSL modem that you're getting problems.... although, in your defence, your modem obviously supports connecting your line straight from the wall to your modem... does your modem/router have any diagnostic utilities such as can the router ping an external IP (rather than a computer within your LAN)?

Comment: Do you have a VDSL faceplate to your home master socket? If so, forget what I said... VDSL faceplates as master sockets (like many do in the UK - I don't) mean you can do away with microfilters... quite good! http://phil.lavin.me.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/fttc-faceplate.jpg

Comment: @BigChris- no Chris, I don't have a VDSL faceplate...

Comment: I connected the splitter and the phone.. and now just the power light is on.. nothing else !!

Comment: Guys, its fixed. Thank you all for your time and suggestions. @BigChris- turns out, I had to use the splitter.

Comment: For ADSL you really should have the filter/splitter in place even if you do not intend connecting a phone.